# Animation is going crazy in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I'm trying to create an effect where clouds float across the screen. I tried wrapping the entire process of creating the cloud shape and cloud group inside of a function, putting the animation in the function, and then putting that function inside of a setInterval. It works in the sense that the animation repeats, except it steadily builds speed and starts going insanely fast.

Does anybody know what's going on here? I used this same strategy in another part of my program and it worked well. The only difference is that I was creating one shape rather than three shapes and a group inside that function.

Please let me know, thanks!

```
var cloudy = function(){

var bigCloud = new Kinetic.Group({});

var cloud1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:257,
    y:28,
    radius:8,
    fill:'white'
})

var cloud2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:283,
    y:28,
    radius:8,
    fill:'white'
})

var cloud3 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:270,
    y:26,
    radius:13,
    fill:'white'
})

bigCloud.add(cloud1);
bigCloud.add(cloud2);
bigCloud.add(cloud3);

skyLayer.add(bigCloud);

    cloudx=500;

var cloudMove = new Kinetic.Animation(function(){
        bigCloud.setX(cloudx);
        cloudx-=2;
    },skyLayer);


cloudMove.start();

};

setInterval(function(){
    cloudy();
},1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new animation with every call to cloudy.

Every new and existing animation is moving bigCloud by -2.

Here's an example that uses 1 animation to animate and also to create new clouds.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jG3BL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    function addCloud(){
        var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x:30,
            y:30,
            radius: 10,
            fill: randomColor(),
        });
        layer.add(circle1);
        layer.draw();
    }

    var newCloudCountdown=120;

    var cloudMove=new Kinetic.Animation(function(){

        var clouds=layer.getChildren();
        clouds.each(function(child){
            child.x(child.x()+.25);
        });

        if(--newCloudCountdown<0){
            addCloud();
            newCloudCountdown=120;
        }

    },layer);

    function randomColor(){ 
        return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }

    // Go
    addCloud();
    cloudMove.start();


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="myButton">Button</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I probably should have been more clear in my original question. I need to create a loop where a new cloud is created and then subsequently animated every second. This code is good but it only helps with creating and animating one cloud.

Comment: Ok, I've revised my answer to both animate existing clouds and also to create new clouds.  Again, the key to stopping your "runaway" animation is to only use 1 animation.  Good luck with your project!